# Can bash rename a folder based on the number of files?

Tags: bash

In ~/Desktop/a/ , I have Folder1, Folder2, etc. Each of these subfolders has files in them. I'd like bash to count the number of files in Folder1, add that count to Folder1's name, then repeat for Folder2 and so on.

So if Folder1 has 10 files and Folder2 has 20, they would be renamed Folder1 [10] and Folder2 [20].

Is this possible? This is the script I've pieced together so far, but I don't know how to proceed further.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ~/Desktop/a/
shopt -s nullglob

for ext in $[f]; do 
  files=( *."$[f]" )

  for f in "${files[@]}"; do
  done 

done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is minimalistic code you need. You can modify and extend it as you want for your real task:

```
mydir=~/Desktop/a/

cd "$mydir"

for f in *
do
    n="$( ls "$f" | wc -l )"
    mv "$f" "$f [$n]"
done
```

Comment: With `nullglob` enabled and the self-defined function `count() { echo $#; };` you can replace `ls "$f" | wc -l` with the safer variant `count "$f"/*`. This correctly counts filenames with newlines in them. As an alternative to `count` you can also define an array: `a=("$f"/*); n="${#a[@]}"`.